# Методы Instagram борьбы с ботами

Tags: instagram, бот, регистрация

Ребята привет. Хочу спросить, какие у Instagram существуют методы контроля в процессе регистрации нового пользователя? Вот я зарегал один акк, а следом второй уже не регается, "попробуйте позже". Я подменяю ip через vpn, и устанавливаю каждый раз новые расширения хрома чтобы изменить отпечаток браузера - и все равно та же ошибка "попробуйте позже". Даже с разных браузеров пытался. Может конечно IP того vpn сервиса которым пользуюсь уже забанены инстой, но вот например исключая этот пункт, какие могут быть еще причины не допускать к регистрации?

Answer (score 0):

@Андрей Петрушов

Сталкивались с таким. Instagram постепенно учится блокировать создание аккаунтов через прокси. По нашим наблюдением особенно часто попадают прокси IPv6.

Возможные варианты решения:

1. Чистим кеш и удаляем данные.
2. Используем разных поставщиков прокси.
3. Если у вас на устройстве-сервере используется любой прокси-инструмент, будь то браузер, специальное дополнение или загруженный профиль – тогда рекомендуем удалить все настройки VPN или же попробовать выполнить процедуру создания профиля с другого ip для проверки.
4. Убедитесь что данные аккаунта уникальны.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!